# Save data in Factory, take that data in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

i have a problem with my code.

This is my factory code:

```
.factory('shareDataService', function() {
    var sharedData = {};

    sharedData.shareData = function(dateFrom, dateTo) {
        var from = dateFrom;
        var to = dateTo;
        alert(from + to);
    };
    return sharedData;
})
```

And this is my controller:

```
.controller('getFormDataCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'shareDataService', function ($rootScope,$scope, $http, shareDataService) {
  $scope.getFromBase = function () {
    shareDataService.shareData($scope.dateFrom, $scope.dateTo)       
  }

  $scope.bookingFormSubmit = function (){
    var array = {
        "from": ''// i want put dateFrom HERE,
        "to": '',// i want put dateTo HERE
        "yacht": $rootScope.yacht_id,
        "customer": {
            "fistname": $scope.firstname,
            "lastname": $scope.lastname,
            "birthday": $scope.birthday,
            "phone": $scope.phone,
            "email": $scope.email,
            "country": $scope.country,
            "city": $scope.city
        }
    }
  }}])
```

This page is build on symfony2. We use sumfony2 forms. 
On first form customer choose date from and to. There is a button "getFromBase()"

I want to save this data in some place to use them later.

Another form is in another ui-view.
There are simple customer text-inputs ( name, lastname, etc.)
On click "bookingFormSubmit()" I take whole data from this form. 
I need to add to this data from my factory ( these 2 variables ) and make an object in Json.

Answer (score 0):

The actual data in that service is a bit too private. You need to expand the scope a bit and provide an accessor.

**Service**

```
.factory('shareDataService', function() {
    var sharedData = {};
    var from, to;

    sharedData.getSharedData = function ()
    {
      return {from: from, to: to};
    };

    sharedData.shareData = function(dateFrom, dateTo) {
        from = dateFrom;
        to = dateTo;
    };

    return sharedData;
})
```

**Usage**

```
.controller('getFormDataCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'shareDataService', function ($rootScope,$scope, $http, shareDataService) {
  $scope.getFromBase = function () {
    shareDataService.shareData($scope.dateFrom, $scope.dateTo)       
  }

  //NEW
  var data = shareDataService.getSharedData;

  $scope.bookingFormSubmit = function (){
    var array = {
        "from": data.from, //NEW
        "to": data.to,     //NEW
        "yacht": $rootScope.yacht_id,
        "customer": {
            "fistname": $scope.firstname,
            "lastname": $scope.lastname,
            "birthday": $scope.birthday,
            "phone": $scope.phone,
            "email": $scope.email,
            "country": $scope.country,
            "city": $scope.city
        }
    }
  }}])
```